# Не понимаю, как в Питоне определить вероятность значения (или интервала) нормально распределенной переменной. Пожалуйста, подскажите, куда взглянуть

Tags: python, distribution

Не понимаю, как в Питоне определить вероятность значения (или интервала) нормально распределенной переменной.  Распределение есть, построил, среднее и сигму, а забыл, как конкретные вероятности по нему определить.  Пожалуйста, подскажите, куда взглянуть.  Заранее спасибо!

Вот какой код у меня уже есть:

```
seriesmean = 1.74 
seriesstd = .08 
sigma = np.sqrt(seriesstd) 
x = np.linspace(seriesmean - 3*sigma, seriesmean + 3*sigma)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, seriesmean, sigma))
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
plt.xlabel('Height') 
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот какой код у меня уже есть:

seriesmean = 1.74

seriesstd = .08

sigma = np.sqrt(seriesstd)


x = np.linspace(seriesmean - 3*sigma, seriesmean + 3*sigma)

plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, seriesmean, sigma))

plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.xlabel('Height')

plt.ylabel('Density')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

Comment: Допустим, как определить вероятность того, что переменная будет больше 1,85?

Или будет в интервале от 1.6 до 1.65?

Comment: Видимо надо взять учебник математики и найти в нем нужные формулы.

Comment: А после учебника математики взять учебник/документацию по Python/scipy.stats и посмотреть на такой метод, как cdf.

Comment: Спасибо, друзья, так и действую.